# Insert value into a table if certain values occur in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to get an insert statement in SQL works that will input a 'Yes' into a column of 'table 1' if a specific value occurs in 'table 2'

so for example, if 'table 2' has 2 columns 'ID' & 'Name' and values of '1' & 'John Smith' then insert a YES into 'table 1' which has a column called 'exists'

```
IF EXISTS 
     (SELECT id, name 
      FROM database.dbo.table2
      WHERE id = '1' 
      and name = 'John Smith' 
)
     INSERT INTO database.dbo.table1 (exists)
     VALUES ('Yes')
```

I found that inserted a new line with just a 'Yes' in the exists column and nulls in the other, but I want it to link up to the row by 'id' in table 1. So that if there is a row with an 'id' of 1 in table1 it will insert it into that row.

I tried giving both table an alias and then adding a where clause at the bottom that matched the id, but it gave an error 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.' after table1.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want an `update`:

```
UPDATE database.dbo.table1
    SET exists = 'Yes'
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM database.dbo.table2 t2
                  WHERE t2.id = 1 AND  -- probably a number, so no quotes
                        t2.name = 'John Smith' AND
                        t2.id = t1.id
                 );
```

This would more normally be written in SQL Server as:

```
UPDATE t1
    SET exists = 'Yes'
    FROM table1 t1 JOIN
         database.dbo.table2 t2
         ON t1.id = t2.id
    WHERE t2.id = 1 AND t2.name = 'John Smith';
```

If you want to `INSERT` the row if it does not exist, you could use `MERGE` or see if the `UPDATE` works and otherwise `INSERT`:

```
UPDATE t1
    SET exists = 'Yes'
    FROM table1 t1 JOIN
         database.dbo.table2 t2
         ON t1.id = t2.id
    WHERE t2.id = 1 AND t2.name = 'John Smith';

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table1 (id, exists)
        VALUES (1, 'Yes')
END;
```